# PHP string manipulation if variable is not empty

Tags: php, string, variables

I am having a small trouble. I hope I am not outputing string properly.Here is the code

```
$icon = ( isset( $tab['icon'] ) && $tab['icon'] ) ?'<i class="$tab['icon']"</i>' : '';
```

I want to output this `<i class="$tab['icon']"</i>`

Thank you.

Comment: You have a **syntax error**

Comment: Are you trying to output the value of $tab['icon'], or the literal text "$tab['icon']"?  You seem to be saying the latter, and that's what it'll do as written if the value is nonfalse.  That is, if you escape your single quotes.

Comment: WOW. I know its syntax error. But where is the error?

Comment: You have single quotes in a single-quoted string.  (And if you fix that, your generated HTML doesn't have a > on its <i tag.)

Comment: yes. I have a variable stored in $tab['icon']. I am using shorthand property. This works perfectly $icon = ( isset( $tab['icon'] ) && $tab['icon'] ) ? $tab['icon'] : '';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not very familiar with the shorthand if statement syntax so here is what I would do longhand. This is assuming `$tab['icon']` needs to be set to the boolean True correct?

```
if(isset($tab['icon']) and $tab['icon']){
   echo "<i class='{$tab[icon]}'>Here it is with a class!</i>";
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have to edit a bit.Here it is  $icon = ( isset( $tab['icon'] ) && $tab['icon'] ) ?"<i class='{$tab[icon]}'</i>" : '';

Comment: Glad you got it to work. Take a look at the question someone attached about the difference between single and double quotes in PHP if you don't already know so you can see why I used them instead of single quotes.